# Django+ HTML: EmptyPage at /HomeFeed/ Error: This page gets no errors

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

Django+ HTML: EmptyPage at /HomeFeed/ Error: This page gets no errors. This happens when i log out and try to access the same page. When I am logged in, I am able to access the same exact page. Does it have to do with my views or my template. If you require a part of my template, please let me know :)

Thank you!

```
def home_feed_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {}
    blog_posts = BlogPost.objects.all()
    context['blog_posts'] = blog_posts  
    type_of_tinc = TypeoftincFilter(request.GET, queryset=BlogPost.objects.all()) 
    context['type_of_tinc'] = type_of_tinc
    paginated_type_of_tinc = Paginator(type_of_tinc.qs, 4)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    tinc_page_obj = paginated_type_of_tinc.get_page(page)

    context['tinc_page_obj'] = tinc_page_obj

    blog_post = BlogPost.objects.filter(author=request.user.id).order_by('date_updated')

    page = request.GET.get('page2')
    own_account_post = Paginator(blog_post, 2)
    try:
        blog_post = own_account_post.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        blog_post = own_account_post.page(2)
    except EmptyPage:
        blog_post = own_account_post.page(blog_post_paginator.num_pages)
 
    context['blog_post'] = blog_post

    return render(request, "HomeFeed/snippets/home.html", context)
```

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
 chief_title                    = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
 author                     = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 body                   = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False)
 slug                   = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
 email                  = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
 username               = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
 date_joined                = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
 last_login             = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
 is_admin               = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 is_active              = models.BooleanField(default=True)
 is_staff               = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 is_superuser           = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Traceback

```
During handling of the above exception (int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'), another exception occurred:
 blog_post = own_account_post.page(page)
```

Comment: `exclude` is what you're looking for

Comment: To confirm, `  type_of_tinc = TypeoftincFilter(request.GET,queryset=BlogPost.objects.exclude(author=request.user.id).order_by('date_updated')) `

Comment: would this be fine?

Comment: almost :) either `.exclude(author=request.user)` or `.exclude(author_id=request.user.id)`

Comment: will it be possible to include .order_by('date_updated'))

Comment: just wondering, would you mind sharing why my answer `(author=request.user.id)` would be wrong?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#database-representation

Comment: if `date_updated` is in the model you query then yes

Comment: hi @TomWojcik i just made my question more challenging :) do you think you can resolve this issue? if possible you can give an official answer so i can give a tick to thank you for your help

Comment: Your page is empty because `request.user` is None, since you are not logged in. When you are trying to query your `blog_post` with `request.user.id` it finds no user, so `blog_posts` is an empty queryset and thats why no posts are showing

Comment: bro, do you know how can i resolve this issue so that i can access the same page even when i log out? because the same code worked for my other paginator in my other views

Comment: well in case you're logged out you might wanna just query all the posts you have

Comment: on my homefeed page i have 2 diff paginators. one for my own post and one for other people's post, so i cant just query all the posts I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I've mentioned in the comment this issue appears because you are logged out and your query doesn't find any `blog_posts` with `.filter(author=request.user.id)`, because the value of the `request.user` is `None` the queryset is empty. To "fix" this you can do something like:

```
def home_feed_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {}
    blog_posts = BlogPost.objects.all()
    context['blog_posts'] = blog_posts  
    type_of_tinc = TypeoftincFilter(request.GET, queryset=BlogPost.objects.all()) 
    context['type_of_tinc'] = type_of_tinc
    paginated_type_of_tinc = Paginator(type_of_tinc.qs, 4)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    tinc_page_obj = paginated_type_of_tinc.get_page(page)

    context['tinc_page_obj'] = tinc_page_obj
    return render(request, "HomeFeed/snippets/home.html", context)


    if request.user.is_authenticated: # the change is here
        blog_posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(author=request.user.id).order_by('date_updated')
    else:
        blog_posts = BlogPost.objects.all()
    
    context['blog_posts'] = blog_posts

    page = request.GET.get('page2')
    own_account_post = Paginator(blog_post, 2)
    try:
        blog_post = own_account_post.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        blog_post = own_account_post.page(2)
    except EmptyPage:
        blog_post = own_account_post.page(blog_post_paginator.num_pages)
 
    context['blog_post'] = blog_post

    return render(request, "HomeFeed/snippets/home.html", context)
```

Comment: bro @SLDem i received this error UnboundLocalError at /HomeFeed/
local variable 'blog_post' referenced before assignment

Comment: does this mean i need to shift my   `context['blog_post'] = blog_post` line above?

Comment: its actually `blog_posts` i've made a mistake, check the edit

Comment: and why do you have 2 returns in the same block of code? :D I Just noticed

Comment: oops pls ignore the first return haha

Comment: wait because at the top i already used blog_posts once, then if i use blog_posts again wont it mean 2 diff things

Comment: this was why i used blog_posts for the first exclude() and then blog_post for the second filter()

Comment: yes the value of `blog_posts` will be changed try using `blog_post`

Comment: bro I have solved the problem, at the bottom should be blog_post for everything startingfrom the is_authenticated and then i shift the context for blog_post up

Answer (score 0):

I think it's caused by this.

blog_post = BlogPost.objects.filter(author=request.user.id)

if a user is not logged in it can't get the request.user.id

so either you make this page only for the authenticated or display something else if user is not authenticated.

you can add the `@login_required()` decorator to your view to make it only the authenticated can view

**or**

```
# this is like what SLDem posted
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    blog_posts = ...
else:
    blog_posts = ...
```